# Android Webview vertically center sliced image in html table

Tags: android, html, css

My android project is loading in a webview an html file that contains a table with a sliced image. When loading the webview, the image is aligned to the upper left corner of the mobile screen. The image scales ok to the width of the mobile screen. 
How to vertically center the image within the screen?

Code:

```
 WebView browser = (WebView) actividad.findViewById(R.id.webView_map);
 browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
 browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 browser.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

 browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 browser.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

 browser.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
 browser.setInitialScale(getScale());   
 browser.loadUrl(imageHtml);

 private final static int MAP_WIDTH = 2500;
 private int getScale(){
    Display display = ((WindowManager)  actividad.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).
        getDefaultDisplay();          
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(dm);

    Double val = Double.valueOf(dm.widthPixels)/Double.valueOf(MAP_WIDTH);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mapa.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img alt=" " src="mapa_general/mapa_general_0_0.png"  style=" border-width: 0px;"></td>
<td><img alt=" " src="mapa_general/mapa_general_0_1.png" style=" border-width: 0px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img alt=" " src="mapa_general/mapa_general_1_0.png" style=" border-width: 0px;"></td>
<td><img alt=" " src="mapa_general/mapa_general_1_1.png" style=" border-width: 0px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html { 
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%; 
}

body { 
  display: table; 
}

#wrapper { 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
}

#wrapper {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I forgot, don't use tables :)

Comment: This worked fine for Android OS versions before 4.1. Is Android 4.1 handling differently webkit?